# In netbeans, how can I tell what function/method I am in?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

In IntelliJ IDE's like *PHP Storm* or *Android Studio*, the current function/method that the cursor is in is displayed at the top of the screen. No such luck in NetBeans.

**Is there any way to find out what function/method the cursor is currently in?**

It is a huge pain if, say, I search for `foo` in my project, and I find `foo` inside of class `Bar`, now I want to know what method of `Bar` I am in. I have to manually scroll up through my code to try and figure it out. Very annoying and time consuming. The *Navigator* tab does not really help here, as it displays the structure of my class but gives no indication of where the cursor is.

Is there a way to find out what method the cursor is in?

Comment: To the downvoter: How do you find what method the cursor is in when you use Netbeans?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread but using "View ">"Show Breadcrumbs" will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. A million times thank you. I was missing that feature and didn't even know what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

Use Navigator window (Window->Navigator or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>).
It should automatically show the current function.
Works for me on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is ***exactly*** what you you're looking for, but if you click on one of the braces (}) at the end of a method/if statement etc, it will display the line directly above/next to the starting brace({). It works with methods, but it requires you to have to scroll to the bottom of the method so it's not *that* helpful, sorry that I couldn't help anymore.

Comment: thanks for your input! yeah, i already know about that one, however it is not a lot of help when i'm 3 levels of braces deep in the middle of a large method :-)

Comment: I wish I knew what that feature/display is called, I'd like to turn it off - To me it's a bit annoying.